# Speeding up SQL to Linq ToList

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0

I have a SQL table with about 380,000 rows.

In SQL SMSS I perform this query:

```
 SELECT Longitude, Latitude, street FROM [Stops].[dbo].[Members]   
 WHERE ABS(Latitude - 51.463419) < 0.005 AND ABS(Longitude - 0.099) < 0.005
```

It returns about 20 results almost instantly.

I have a WCF webserice to expose my Data to my Windows phone application:

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    double curLatitude = 51.463;
    double curLongitude = 0.099;

    public List<Member> GetMembers()
    {
        DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext();
        var members = from member in db.Members                            
where (Convert.ToDouble(member.Latitude) - curLatitude) < 0.005 && (Convert.ToDouble(member.Longitude) - curLongitude) < 0.005

select member;
        return members.ToList();
    }
}
```

I beleive it is doing the same query, but also adding the items to a List.

The problem is, is that it takes 7+ minutes then I get some strange exception so never completes. The WCF service tester in VS2010 just fills up with memory and uses lots of CPU when permforming this.
My feeling is that the ToList is doing something odd?

Comment: Just to add: you might want to look at "live" profiling tools; for example, we use (and wrote) "mvc-mini-profiler" to make sure we always have direct access to ***every*** query to the DB, along with parameter values, timings, row-counts, repeats etc. We can then check trivially to see if anything unexpected happens. And the impact is virtually nil (it would have to be; we are very, very fussy about performance). I could, for example, tell you *at a glance* how many SQL queries (and which TSQL) were used to build this page, and how long each took.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the abs-part in your LINQ version.

**Some side notes.**
You can track the SQL query in at least two possible ways.

1. Use SQL profiler and check the query there (then you can paste the query in SQL Management Studio and compare the output to your query above).
2. Insert `db.Log = Console.Out;` (or another `TextWriter`) and check the output window in Visual Studio.

You should dispose your DataClassesDataContext, the best way is to put it in a using block:

```
public List<Member> GetMembers()
{
    using(DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        var members = from member in db.Members                            
        where (Convert.ToDouble(member.Latitude) - curLatitude) < 0.005
            && (Convert.ToDouble(member.Longitude) - curLongitude) < 0.005
        select member;
        return members.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I added Math.Abs. Loads in a seconds now. It was probably returning 6000 results otherwise. I feel silly now :-)

Comment: @Ash, removing the abs would return half the world or something like that. Returning something like 100.000 records takes a lot more time than returning 7. The abs-part narrows it down to the points very close to the actual position.

Comment: what advantage does it give to dispose it by putting it in a block?

Comment: @DanSewell When disposing the DataContext the underlying `DbConnection` is closed immediately. Otherwise the sql connection might be dangling around open, but unused.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues here:

- (edit: ignore this point; I misread the 380,000 as being the data being fetched) that is a very large volume of data to query and bring over the network; how long, for example, does it take in Query Analyzer? It will take at least that long anywhere
- when loading that into LINQ-to-SQL you have materialisation overheads, and the identity-manager overhead; the latter can be solved by disabling object tracking on the data-context; the former is trickier - if you suspect this is significant (it can be, sometimes) maybe something like "dapper" can load this instead (it has a far more efficient materialiser, and does not include an identity manager)
- WCF has to serialize this data, which can take quite a lot of CPU and memory - it then needs to come over the network (which takes bandwidth). If you are free to change the format, other serializers might save both CPU and bandwidth here.

So; the first thing to do is identify where the time is going.

- I would start by running it from Query Analyser; maybe an index is missing?
- set ObjectTrackingEnabled to false
- after that, separate the data-access from WCF to see which is the culprit - time *just* the data-to-a-list step
- after that, time DataContractSerializer serialising this data and measure the size of the data when serialized (personally, I'd then compare to protobuf-net - but that might not be an option, depending on your scenario)
- an then measure the time on the network

Any or all of those might need optimising here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It turns out it was just returning too many results with my query in C#. What is the query analyser? I havent found that yet.

Comment: @Dan Query Analyser is the old name (sorry, my bad) for SQL Server Management Studio, the ideal tool for writing, testing and optimising your SQL queries

Comment: Query Analyzer is an old tool, now replaced with SQL Management Studio.

Comment: ahh yes, I am using SSMS (also known as!)

Comment: I am a bit confused here as the SQL to Linq qury in my C# is different from a normal SQL query. will SSMS understand this?

Comment: @Dan you can obtain the TSQL that LINQ-to-SQL generates by any of: dataContext.Log, a profiling tool like mvc-mini-profiler, SQL trace, or a number of other SQL tools